# Asp regexp result listing

Tags: regex, listview, asp-classic

```
 strDeger1 = """ >"
strDeger2 = "</a>"
strBaslikBul = VeriBul(strDeger1, strDeger2)
Response.Write strBaslikBul
Response.Write "<hr>" 

Set RegEx = New RegExp
 RegEx.IgnoreCase = True
 RegEx.Global = True
 RegEx.Pattern = "(" & BaslangicDegeri & ")(.+?)(" & BitisDegeri & ")"
Set Sonuc = RegEx.Execute(Trim(tr(Mid(HTTPObj2.GetURL,29600,254000))))
For Each i In Sonuc
 VeriBul =  i.SubMatches(1)
Next


If IsEmpty(VeriBul) Then VeriBul = "Sonuc Yok"
Set RegEx = Nothing
Set Sonuc = Nothing
Set objXmlHttp = Nothing
End Function
```

I have like this code, I'm trying to make listing all for records. But just one of record viewing.

How I can fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Also need to concat for each match. Modify line 
`VeriBul =  i.SubMatches(1)` with `VeriBul =  VeriBul & i.SubMatches(1)`